# Cannot use show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My issue: When I add another text input, I cannot show/hide it.

```
<html>
 <head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

        $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        });

        $(".slidingDiv1").hide();
        $(".show_hide1").show();

        $('.show_hide1').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv1").slideToggle();
        });

});

var counter = 1;
var limit = 3;
function addInput(divName){

mainCanvasDiv = document.createElement("div");
mainCanvasDiv.className = "slidingDiv1";
mainCanvasDiv.style.display = "none";

var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.id = "dynamicInput" + counter;
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<a href='#' class='show_hide1'>Show/hide</a>";
          mainCanvasDiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text'  name='dynamicInput" + counter +"1'><br><input type='text' name='dynamicInput" + counter +"2'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv).appendChild(mainCanvasDiv);
          counter++;

}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
 var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
            document.getElementById('sort').value = newOrder;
        }
    });
});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="lost.php" method="POST">
<div id="sortable">
<div id="dynamicInput">
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
<input type="text" name="myInputs[]">

</div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('sortable');"><br />
<input type="hidden" name="sort" id="sort" value="">
<input type=submit value="GO!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any advice?

Update:
I have changed 
    $('.show_hide1').click(function(){ 
to 
    $('.show_hide1').on("click", "div a.show_hide1", function(){

Maybe I am doing something wrong, I am not strong in JS.

Comment: Try setting up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) instead. Much easier to work with.

Comment: @JohnConde Here: http://jsfiddle.net/aWhJQ/ Please don't say "instead", the code needs to be in the post.

Comment: Why are you including jQuery 1.8.3 AND 1.9.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your click events for:

```
            $("#sortable").on("click","div a.show_hide", function() {
                $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
            });

            $("#sortable").on("click","div a.show_hide1", function() {
                $(".slidingDiv1").slideToggle();
            });
```

Comment: Done, but now it is not sortable

Answer (score 2):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Yhp3c/

You need to use `live` instead of `click` as `live` also targets future (read: DOM scripted) elements.

Edit: As stated in comments: Use `on` instead of `live`.

Comment: `live` is deprecated, use `on`.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your post, jsfiddle is not loading for me (it's painfully slow).

Comment: `live` has been REMOVED in jquery 1.9

Comment: Please don't use `.live()`. Use `.on()` or `.delegate()`

Comment: I have changed `$('.show_hide1').click(function(){` to `$('.show_hide1').on("click", "div a.show_hide1", function(){` . DO not work =(